# Restrict user to upload file from downloads folder only

Tags: java, android

Is there any way in which we can restrict the user to upload files (PDF, Docx and Images) from downloads folder only? Like he can't see any other directory from he can choose a file from? Actually I have made an app in which pdf files are not getting the right path for WhatsApp Documents and docs in Recents folder on android 11 I have tried many solutions but nothing helped. So I am thinking if we can restrict the user to Downloads only?

Comment: No, most (all?) browsers even the web server access to the path of the uploaded file. What would prevent a user from copying a file to the Download folder and simply uploading it then?

Comment: Right, I think I should focus on fixing that issue. Thank you

Comment: You are still trying to get a path for an uri. Which is wrong to begin with. And because you dont manage you will create all new constraints which makes your app worse and worse. Stop trying to get a path. You dont need it.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Can you guide me with any legit solution? I am actually new to android. I got to know about scoped storage in android 11 but couldn't find any legit implementation for it.